# What do I have to do to get my file system to recognize foreign characters?

Tags: languages

I have some MP3 files that have Cyrillic in the mp3 data, as well as being named Сyrillic (the file names themselves as in "музыка.mp3". Is there some additional language package that can install to have my music player and file system render the Cyrillic data correctly?

I realize these are two separate features. I'm happy to get answers for both.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption would be you need to install some kind of language package, buy a phone from the country of origin for that language, or convert the files back to English language.

When I go to Settings > Language & keyboard and look at the languages I can only choose from English and Spanish. So to install another language search the market for it like so, "Russian Language Pack". Install and go back to the language place in settings and select it. Then see if you can play the files.

If that doesn't work you are going to have to try the other two options.